# Can't edit Youtube video title using Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Im trying to make an extension to change videos on youtube, but i can't edit the video title or channel name.

While i can change the country sign that shows up next to the Youtube logo with:

```
let country = document.getElementById("country-code").innerHTML = "xyz";
```

I can't do the same with the video title.

I don't know why this is a thing?

Answer (score 1):

what about this

```
document.querySelector('h1.title.style-scope.ytd-video-primary-info-renderer').innerText="xyz"
```